# "int" and "const int" initialization and conversion in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, constants

I wrote the following line of code in my program:

```
const int *dims = {4};
```

but it reported me the following error:

**"a value of type int cannot be used to initialize an entity of type const int"**

Can anyone tell me what happened and teach me a way to fix it?(On the condition that the array of `dims` is still `const`)

Comment: Well, like it says you cannot initialize a `const int*` with `4`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Because I want to use a function which the other guy programmed, which takes the argument const int *dims. And I want to use int a safe way such that I can avoid the auto type conversion, etc

Comment: Dunno know if this can be regarded as a correct choice or safe choice of doing so : int dims1 = {4};const int *dims = &dims1;

Comment: for matrices use double pointers

Comment: Doesn't the error message have a `*`?

Comment: @boxed__l: Not necessarily. To use a pointer to pointer, you need to allocate the rows explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `const int *dims = {4};` means assign the pointer dims with the value 4. 
But why would you want a pointer to point to the memory location 4? It's so unlikely that that is what you want that doing it isn't allowed.

Here are some options for getting a pointer to a const int with value 4:

```
const int *dims = new int(4);  // beware someone needs to delete dims
```

For automatic lifetime, as in on the stack:

```
const int autoDims(4);     // Will be deleted when autoDims goes out of scope
const int *dims(&autoDims);
```

or:

```
const int dims[] = {4};    // Will be deleted when dims goes out of scope
```

If you really want a pointer with the value 4 you have to explicitly cast to the pointer type:

```
const int *dims = (int *)4;
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining because you are trying to initialize a pointer with an integer.

The function you are referring to is probably expecting to be passed an array. You can call it with a constant array as follows:

```
const int dim[4] = {1,2,3,4};

foo(dim);
```